# Play 2 framework clean in memory DB

Tags: java, sql, database, junit, playframework-2.0

In Play 2 Framework we can create in memory database for testing purposes and then load yaml file into the DD.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
   start(fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase()));
}

Ebean.save((List) Yaml.load("test-data.yml"));
```

The question is how to easily clean the DB (drop all tables)?

Something like `Ebean.clean()` or `Ebean.dropAll()`, but it does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

`inMemoryDatabase()` uses a random database name, so each time you create it, it should return you a new database.  Nevertheless, if you want to drop all tables, just create an `@After` method, and use the `DB` class to get a jdbc connection, then you can issue a drop database SQL statement.